# Get generic type of a class implementing a generic interface

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have an Interface

```
public interface IConfigDao<T> {}
```

I have a class which implements this interface,

```
public class ConfigDaoJedisImpl<T> implements IConfigDao<T> {}
```

I am instantiating the class a follows,

```
IConfigDao<UserLimitConfig> configDao = new ConfigDaoJedisImpl<>();
```

Now in the constructor of `ConfigDaoJedisImpl` I want to get the class object of `UserLimitConfig` (It is the generic type with which the interface was instantiated).
Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible, but only through a parameterized subclass. See Guava's TypeToken and Jackson's TypeReference for examples.

Comment: Also see possible solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084670/how-to-get-the-class-of-type-variable-in-java-generics

Comment: You might find [my other answer](/a/32332375/466738) helpful

Comment: Pass the class in the constructor. There are certain cases when you can get the generic type through reflection, but generics are intended to give you compile-time safety only, so reflecting on it would be (arguably) somewhat of a misuse.